# DTedit and Shiny: how can i show specific data on a table basing on a selected row of another table?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, rendering, dt

this is my first question and first time here, hope that the structure of the question is right.
I am an entry-level user of shiny and i am using the DTedit package to create datatables for my application.
I have to create two datatables. In the first one are simply shown some data (no problem in doing it), while in the second one values of additional columns are shown depending on the row selected in the first table. In a nutshell, the second table is used to provide more information of the row selected in the first table.

Here you have the code for doing it with DT package.

```
                  Project     Counts     Inventory
                  A          25         100
                  B          20         120
                  C          10          50
                  ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- read.table(text="
                  ProjectID     Sub_Project     Counts       Date
                  A            1              5      2017-05-01
                  A            2             10      2017-05-01
                  A            2             10      2017-06-01
                  B            1             40      2017-05-01
                  B            1             20      2017-06-01
                  B            1             20      2017-07-01
                  B            2             40      2017-05-01
                  C            1             15      2017-05-01
                  C            1             35      2017-06-01
                  ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Dashboard'),
  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel('Sequencing', 
               fluidRow(
                 column(12, 
                        dataTableOutput('project_table'), 
                        dataTableOutput('subproject_table'))
               )
      )
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$project_table <- renderDataTable(df1, options = list(pageLength = 10))


  output$subproject_table <- renderDataTable({
    s = input$project_table_rows_selected
    project <- unique(df1[s,c("Project")])
    df2[df2$ProjectID %in% project, ]})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Basically i need to do the same but with DTedit package.
I am blocked with my project, i hope that someone can help me.
Thank you very much